# iframe: Not able to run youtube videos on my html page

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, embed

I am new to HTML and when I am trying to embed a youtube video in my html page using iframe tag, then it is getting embedded very well. Please see code below:

```
<iframe width="420" height="320" src="https://youtube.com/embed/FiMl6n64bTg"></iframe>
```

But when i am trying to run that video in my html page then it is showing

> The video contains content from multi screen media. It is restricted from playback in certain sites. Watch on Youtube..

How can i run youtube video in my html page without this error/issue.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: so you want to rip multi screen media's content.

Comment: I just want to play a simple youtube in my html page..

Comment: Probably, you just can't do it. Your users will have to go to Youtube to watch the video; or you'll have to download the video, upload it to another server, and link that one (risking getting in legal trouble with Multi Screen Media)

Comment: @user2977907 ...and the owners of the video don't want you to do that. Read the message youtube is giving.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" 
width="420" height="320" src="https://youtube.com/embed/FiMl6n64bTg"
frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: if you copy "https://youtube.com/embed/FiMl6n64bTg" to the browser, it is the same as "This video contains content from multi screen media, who has blocked if from display on this website"

Comment: I added second one, which can play in both browser and fiddle. It looks like your video issue. I updated fiddle as http://jsfiddle.net/j3gwkgja/1/

Comment: so you puy an unrelated video in their with no playback restrictions on it,well done. Read the message youtube is giving. are you telling me you can play the original video ?